# Powerbuilder query

Tags: powerbuilder

How I can search a .txt file in any directory(i.e. c:\,d:\ etc.) using file functions in PowerBuilder?

Comment: Are you looking to search a directory *for* *.txt files, or scan the *.txt files in a directory for specific content? One directory or subtrees? And what PB version and target type?

Answer (score 6):

So, if all you're doing is looking for files, you can do this with a listbox.DirList(), or if you want to do this without being tied to a window or a control, you can call WinAPI functions to do this:

```
Function long FindFirstFileW (ref string filename, ref os_finddata findfiledata) library "KERNEL32.DLL" alias for "FindFirstFileW"
Function boolean FindNextFileW (long handle, ref os_finddata findfiledata) library "KERNEL32.DLL" alias for "FindNextFileW"
```

where os_finddata is defined as

```
unsignedlong        ul_fileattributes
os_filedatetime     str_creationtime
os_filedatetime     str_lastaccesstime
os_filedatetime     str_lastwritetime
unsignedlong        ul_filesizehigh
unsignedlong        ul_filesizelow
unsignedlong        ul_reserved0
unsignedlong        ul_reserved1
character       ch_filename[260]
character       ch_alternatefilename[14]
```

and os_filedatetime is defined as

```
unsignedlong        ul_lowdatetime
unsignedlong        ul_highdatetime
```

If you want examples of how to use these, look in PFC (PowerBuilder Foundation Classes, available at [CodeXchange](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1059036&id=1059036)) at the object (pfcapsrv.pbl)pfc_n_cst_filesrvunicode.of_DirList (). (That's where these prototypes and the structures are copied from, BTW.)

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ListBox` control to get a list of files/directories based on a given string pattern (*.txt, myfile.txt, .etc).  Look at the `DirList` function in the help.  And here is an example from [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/pbtech.htm#DIRECTORY%20FILE%20LIST%20WITHOUT%20A%20WINDOW) showing how to use a ListBox control without putting it visually on a window.

```
string ls_files[]
window lw_1
listbox llb_1
int li_items, li_i

Open( lw_1 )

lw_1.openUserObject( llb_1 )

llb_1.DirList( sFileSpec, uFileType )

li_items = llb_1.TotalItems()

For li_i = 1 to li_items

ls_files[ li_i ] = llb_1.Text( li_i )

Next

lw_1.closeUserObject( llb_1 )

Close( lw_1 )
```

Comment: It is very annoying that you have to have a control on a window for the DirList to work. It adds unnecessary steps, especially when I'm working from an NVO.

Comment: I believe it does not have to be visible. You just add the listbox in code and get rid of it.